# Angular : How to retain the filters data while routing

Tags: angular

### Components :

```
         Search Page -> Search Component ( Where Filters are provided & 
                        based on those filters, Data is retrieved from DB 
                        & Displayed in Mat Table)

         Form Page   -> Form Component (Based on the record selection, 
                        that particular record  details are shown in the 
                        form )

         Home Page   -> Home Component   (router-outlet)
```

Issue here is , If I move to form page & back to search page, My filters data & grid data is lost.

If I create Parent & Child relation, then filter data & grid data is retained but sorting is lost.

### Convention :

Routing from Search Page   to Form Page   ( Working Fine )

Routing from Form Page     to Search Page ( Issue mentioned above is happening )

Comment: could you provide some code?

Answer (score 0):

You should probably have a shared service (a service provided in 'root') and just store the filter state in that. There are other alternatives to passing data between routes/auxiliary routes but because you want a specific state that isn't going to change until the user decides, a shared service is the way forward. This will allow you to keep a static state, until the user explicitly changes it.

This would encapsulate all your logic in that service, and each time the user wants to change the filters, the service can just call on some of it's private members.